# Rest API with LocomotiveJs using CORS. Works on local machine but not on Amazon or Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, cors, locomotivejs

Rest API with LocomotiveJs using CORS. Works on local machine but not on Amazon or Heroku

I did a REST api using LocomotiveJs and now I'm trying to enable CORS on it.
I added the following code to my "all" environment (config/environments/all.js).

```
this.use(function crossOrigin(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Authentication");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");

    return next();
});
```

It works on my local machine but when I deploy it to Heroku or AWS I got a 404 Http Error when the client sends the OPTIONS command.

In order to isolate the problem, I developed a simple Express app, with the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Authentication");
  next();
 });

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send({ 'Hello' : 'World' });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
```

And this code worked when deployed to Heroku!

Do you guys have any opinion on why it worked on my local machine and didn't work on the servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

Now I'm using this connect middleware: https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors

Then I just changed my all.js file adding the following line:

```
this.use(cors());
```

I deployed it on Heroku and works now.